# How to multithread a function in Flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a function that gets the current price of any currency that i choose using the [financial google](https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=KGS&meta=ei%3DrD_0WeDcKsmLswHihJmoDQ), i want to multithread it so i can send any request separately .

Here is my **code**:

```
def currency_converter(amount, currency):
    url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a={}&from=KGS&to={}&meta=ei%3DmSr0WeHCCYvBsAH8n6OIBA'.format(amount, currency)
    urlHandler = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = urlHandler.read()
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    num = bsoup.find('span').text.split()[0]
    return float(num)

@main_route.app_template_filter('currency_converter')
def thread_me(amount, currency):
    t = threading.Thread(target=currency_converter, args=[amount, currency])
    t.start()
    t.join()
    return t
```

here is how i run the filter inside my template:

`{{ product.price|float|currency_converter('RUB') }} руб`

Here i am returning the t value , i want to return the data from the api , please how can i make that done ??

Another problem that i forgot to mention that, if i opened any product page the page delays for about 10 seconds !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try multiprocessing instead:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

#currency_converter code

@main_route.app_template_filter('currency_converter')
def thread_me(amount, currency):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

    result = pool.apply_async(currency_converter, (amount, currency))

    return result.get()
```

Comment: it worked but why i am getting the delay when loading the page ?? , is there any way to get that done without any kind of delay ??

Comment: It could be anything. I would suggest printing the time before and after a block of your code to see how long it took to pinpoint exactly what is causing it.

Comment: Inside the page i am running the filter about 10 times so i can get all the products prices at the same time, maybe this what causing the delay ??

Comment: It could be. Like I said, the only way to know for sure is to time it yourself.

Comment: I understand , however thanks for your interest mate it worked perfectly :)

Comment: @swordfish glad I could help.